# Ajax/FormData is rounding my decimal values?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I am sending the data from a form to my php script, and I am using the `new FormData()` method of grabbing the form's values. However, there are a few values I append afterwards which are not actually included in the form:

```
var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById('poForm'));
fd.append('file[]', document.getElementById("file"));
fd.append('itemTotals', itemTotals);
fd.append('subTotals', subTotals);
fd.append('transTotal', transTotal);
fd.append('transDate', document.getElementById('transDate').value);
fd.append('itemArray', JSON.stringify(itemArray));
```

The issue I am having is, for example: `itemTotals` value is 23.97, it gets rounded up to 24.

I am not sure super familiar with using this new FormData method, I am only using it because it seemed to work good for having multiple files uploaded through ajax. How do I fix this issue of the number values rounding up?

Comment: Where is it getting rounded? When you watch the request is the value rounded before it is sent to the PHP script? After it comes back, in the response? Can you give us some more to go on?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `FormData` because it doesn't manipulate values.

Comment: Is this really a php question? If so, how?

Answer (score -1):

The answer ended up being that my database wasn't accepting decimal numbers in the correct format..